# Como faço um botão submeter um formulario e reproduzir um som

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou fazendo uma aplicação web que quando a pessoa clicar no botão submeta o formulario e automaticamente seja reproduzindo um som de alerta,mas não estou conseguindo reproduzir o som e submeter o formlario ,ele so executa uma função ignorando a outra.

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onClick="$('#audio')[0].play();$('#chamarPainel').submit();"> Chamar </button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma boa abordagem é usar `setTimeout` para realizar a submissão do formulário após um tempo determinado (após tocar o áudio, por exemplo).

Você pode fazer algo assim:

```js
const audio = new Audio('https://lffg-archive.github.io/sopt/for-sure.mp3');
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  // Previne a submissão original do formulário:
  event.preventDefault();

  // Toca o áudio:
  audio.play();

  setTimeout(() => {
    // Após 1 segundo (1000 milissegundos), faça a submissão do formulário:
    form.submit();
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<form action="/action" method="post">
  <button type="submit">Submeter</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Deu certo ,Vlw.

Comment: cara,agora nao ta dando mais certo ,ele ta ignorando o play e ta fazendo o submit